# JavaScript: How to find out when images are turned off in browser?

Tags: javascript

Would like cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 6):

You may take a look at this [post](http://www.mawhorter.net/projects/facelift-projects/detecting-if-images-are-disabled-css-on-images-off-scenario) (first hit on [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=javascript+detect+images+disabled+browser&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)).

Comment: Link currently down. Wayback Machine cached page: http://web.archive.org/web/20100214115656/http://www.mawhorter.net/projects/facelift-projects/detecting-if-images-are-disabled-css-on-images-off-scenario; perhaps this is as good: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/10/detecting-if-images-are-disabled-in-browsers/

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    detectImageEnabledMode({
        onDetectImageIsDisabled:function(){
            alert('disabled');
        },
        onDetectImageIsEnabled:function(){
            alert('enabled');
        }
    });
    function detectImageEnabledMode(options){
        /* define disabled/enabled actions */
        var actionCounter = 0;
        var enabledAction = (options.onDetectImageIsEnabled && typeof(options.onDetectImageIsEnabled)=='function')?options.onDetectImageIsEnabled:function(){};
        var enaledActionRun = function(){
            if(actionCounter) return;
            actionCounter++;
            enabledAction();
        }
        var disabledAction = (options.onDetectImageIsDisabled && typeof(options.onDetectImageIsDisabled)=='function')?options.onDetectImageIsDisabled:function(){};
        var disabledActionRun = function(){
            if(actionCounter) return;
            actionCounter++;
            disabledAction();
        }
        /* create image */
        var img = new Image();
        var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft Internet Explorer') != -1){// ie
            img.onload = enaledActionRun;
            img.onabort = enaledActionRun;
            img.onerror = enaledActionRun;
            img.src = currentTime+'.'+currentTime+'?time='+currentTime;
            setTimeout(function(){
                disabledActionRun();
            }, 0);
        }else if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Opera') != -1) {// opera
            img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw=="+'?time='+(new Date()).getTime();
            if(img.complete){
                enaledActionRun();
            }else{
                disabledActionRun();
            }
        }else{// other
            img.src = currentTime+'.'+currentTime+'?time='+currentTime;
            if(img.complete){
                disabledActionRun();
            }else{
                enaledActionRun();
            }
        }
    }
    // tested in: ff 2+, opera 9+, chrome, safari 4+, ie 6+
</script>
```

[Live demo.](http://gospodarets.com/developments/detect-image-enabled-mode/)
The only problem - the minimum asynchronous in ie:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 disabledActionRun();
}, 0);
```

Comment: Keep getting the following error in console panel: GET http://URL/1340274425981.1340274425981?time=1340274425981 404 (Not Found) is there a way around this, its on both with or without images