# How to detect if images are disabled in browser?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: How to find out when images are turned off in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896904/javascript-how-to-find-out-when-images-are-turned-off-in-browser)

What's the easiest way to detect if a user is browsing with images turned off and add another stylesheet to the head then?

Is there a short javascript snippet that could do the trick and is well browser supported?

Comment: Thank you. Question beside: Should I better delete this post then?

Comment: Duplicate questions are not all bad. It can be useful to have multiple wordings of a problem "pointed" at a canonical answer, by way of "this question closed as duplicate of [link]." When in doubt, [ask a question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), or flag for ♦ moderator attention with your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    detectImageEnabledMode({
        onDetectImageIsDisabled:function(){
            alert('disabled');
        },
        onDetectImageIsEnabled:function(){
            alert('enabled');
        }
    });
    function detectImageEnabledMode(options){
        /* define disabled/enabled actions */
        var actionCounter = 0;
        var enabledAction = (options.onDetectImageIsEnabled && typeof(options.onDetectImageIsEnabled)=='function')?options.onDetectImageIsEnabled:function(){};
        var enaledActionRun = function(){
            if(actionCounter) return;
            actionCounter++;
            enabledAction();
        }
        var disabledAction = (options.onDetectImageIsDisabled && typeof(options.onDetectImageIsDisabled)=='function')?options.onDetectImageIsDisabled:function(){};
        var disabledActionRun = function(){
            if(actionCounter) return;
            actionCounter++;
            disabledAction();
        }
        /* create image */
        var img = new Image();
        var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft Internet Explorer') != -1){// ie
            img.onload = enaledActionRun;
            img.onabort = enaledActionRun;
            img.onerror = enaledActionRun;
            img.src = currentTime+'.'+currentTime+'?time='+currentTime;
            setTimeout(function(){
                disabledActionRun();
            }, 0);
        }else if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Opera') != -1) {// opera
            img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw=="+'?time='+(new Date()).getTime();
            if(img.complete){
                enaledActionRun();
            }else{
                disabledActionRun();
            }
        }else{// other
            img.src = currentTime+'.'+currentTime+'?time='+currentTime;
            if(img.complete){
                disabledActionRun();
            }else{
                enaledActionRun();
            }
        }
    }
    // tested in: ff 2+, opera 9+, chrome, safari 4+, ie 6+
</script>
```

[Live demo.](http://gospodarets.com/developments/detect-image-enabled-mode/)
The only problem - the minimum asynchronous in ie:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 disabledActionRun();
}, 0);
```